# Configure Spring REST Controller without DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, rest, web.xml

I want to setup Rest Controller using Spring without DispatcherServlet.

I have worked with Rest Controller with Spring MVC's dispatcher servlet but I am not sure how to setup controllers without it.

Below is the code that I tried:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/somemapping")
public class SomeControllerImpl implements SomeController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    @Override
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<DO> getAllDO() {
        return service.getAllDO();
    }

}
```

When I tried accessing above controller using "localhost:8080/appName/somemapping/" it gave 404 error.

Edit: I have Websphere application server. If that has something to do with my issue.

Comment: try to localhost:8080/somemapping/

Comment: The `DispatcherServlet` *is the component* that connects the servlet container to the Spring controllers. This is like asking how to set up your car's wheels without a transmission.

Comment: @chrylis So you are saying that it would not be possible to use rest controllers without DispatcherServlet?

Comment: Correct. (Or WebFlux, but that's an equivalent Spring piece for the reactive model.)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the above controller's GET method using http://localhost:8080/somemapping/

Instead of giving `@RequestMapping(value = "/")`,  you can also give value as `value=""`

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but now it gave an error "servlet class was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred".

Comment: The complete error is "servlet class was found, but a resource injection failure has occurred java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.example.controller.SomeController.<init>()".

Comment: @damndemon share the whole stack trace.

Comment: I think the issue is with the constructor of your controller. Are you implementing parameterized constructor without default constructor? If yes, Add a default constructor